# How to add symbols(cross, star sign, numbers 1/2..) on some grids in a image using image.plot in R?

Tags: r, netcdf

i have a temperature netcdf data.i want to plot two images(1st maximum temp and 2nd mean temp) using field package in R by image.plot function. I want that grids in 1st image have value greater then like 300K show cross/star sign on that grids in 2nd image.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the x and y, it makes it really easy to get at the indices which satisfy the criteria in the first matrix to then place the symbol on the second. I give a trivial example below.

First, we make up data.

```
library(fields)
test <-  matrix(runif(100),ncol=10)
test2 <- matrix(1:100, ncol=10)
```

Then we can set up the plotting environment and visualize the data.

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2),ncol=2))
image.plot(x=1:10, y=1:10, z=unlist(test))
image.plot(x=1:10, y=1:10, z=unlist(test2))
```

Then we determine which cells satisfy the criteria of being larger than 0.75 (this is arbitrary).

```
inds <- which(test > 0.75, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Then we can use `points` to add the star symbol to the center of the cell in `test2` in which our criteria from matrix `test` is satisfied.

```
points(x=inds[,1], y=inds[,2], pch=8)
```

[image]

Comment: "points(x=inds[,1], y=inds[,2], pch=8)" this is not working. May be due to lat-long on place of x & y values.

Comment: I would recommend not using image.plot for dealing with spatial data. You can use the `raster` package to make something that looks similar to an image.plot, and then overlay spatial points with the points command in a similar way as I have done in my answer. The `raster` package has it's own data structure, but it's relatively intuitive. values(rasterObject) will give you the values, and coordinates(rasterObject) will give you the coordinates (provided you have the memory to do those operations).